# How to convert a sparse array to a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, sparse-arrays

```
s = Import["hello.mat"];
t = GraphEmbedding[Graph[s[[1]]], "GridEmbedding"];
```

I get the following error:

> GraphEmbedding::graph:     A graph object is expected at position 1 in
>
> ```
> GraphEmbedding[Graph[SparseArray[<1232>, {223, 223}]], GridEmbedding].
> ```

I would prefer to do `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` and then `"GridEmbedding"`. What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The converstion between sparse arrays and graphs can be done with `AdjacencyMatrix` and `AdjacencyGraph` or `IncidenceMatrix` and `IncidenceGraph`. The file you provided [here](http://cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/MM/HB/ash292.tar.gz) is a `AdjacencyMatrix`.

To get the `Graph` and `GraphEmbedding`try tje following:

```
m = Import["...\\ash292.mtx"];
graph = AdjacencyGraph[m]
graphEmb = GraphEmbedding[graph]
```

> [image]
>
> {{1.97816, 14.9905}, {2.07528, 14.6501},
>   {2.25118, 14.7393}, [...] }

You can add the option `"GridEmbedding"` to `GraphEmbedding` but from what you wrote I don't thinks that's what you need.

**[Second case](http://cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/MM/Pothen/mesh3e1.tar.gz)**:

```
m = Import["...\\mesh3e1.mtx"]
m = SparseArray[Most[# -> 1 & /@ ArrayRules[m][[All, 1]]]];
graph = SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[m]]
```

> [image]

Just for completeness here is an example on how one could take `EdgeWeights` into account when plotting graphs. Weights have to be dealt with separately in this case because `AdjacencyGraph` can't deal with non integer weights. Edges and vertices are colored by weight and degree just to make it fun. (weights are modified)

```
m = Import["...\\mesh3e1.mtx"];
m2 = SparseArray[Most[# -> 1 & /@ ArrayRules[m][[All, 1]]]];
graph = SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[m2]];
weights = m[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ EdgeList[graph];
edgeStyle = 
  Flatten@{Thick, 
    Flatten[{#[[1]] -> #[[2]]} & /@ 
      Transpose[{EdgeList[graph], 
        ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#] & /@ weights}]]};
vertexStyle = 
  Flatten[{#[[1]] -> #[[2]]} & /@ 
    Transpose[{Range[Length@VertexDegree[graph]], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Rescale[VertexDegree[graph]]}]];
graph2 = Graph[EdgeList[graph], Background -> Black, 
  EdgeWeight -> 1/(weights + 1)^5 (* <- weights modified*), 
  EdgeStyle -> edgeStyle, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle, 
  GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
    "EdgeWeighted" -> True}]
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to add that the layout can be modified as:

`AdjacencyGraph[m, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]`

or:

`AdjacencyGraph[m, GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding"]`

Comment: here 's' is a sparse array. (s = Import["hello.mat"];)
What should I do to get GridEmbedding for this sparse array?
When I do m = AdjacencyMatrix[s]
g = AdjacencyGraph[m]

Comment: I get the following error:
AdjacencyMatrix::graph: 
   A graph object is expected at position 1 in 
    AdjacencyMatrix[{SparseArray[<1252>, {240, 240}]}].

Out[5]= AdjacencyMatrix[{SparseArray[<1252>, {240, 240}]}]

Comment: There are several ways to represent a graph as a sparse array. Please provide the array in question, otherwise I dont see a way to help you any further.

Comment: The sparsearray is matlab sparse matrix.
This is what I do
1. In Matlab I Save a sparse matrix as .mat file.
Sparse matrix in matlab stores only nonzeros in the matrix  as (2,3) -> 50, (3,5) -> 60. This means that at 2nd row and 3rd column entry is 50 and the entry at 3rd and 5th column is 60.
2. Load the .mat file as s= Import["hello.mat"] and then do t = GraphEmbedding[Graph[s[[1]]], "GridEmbedding"];

Comment: Is it so hard to just upload an example file?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know where can I upload the mat file. I get the same error with the mtx file.
You can find the mtx file here: 
http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/MM/HB/ash292.tar.gz
I do is filename ="hello.mtx";
s = Import[filename];

Comment: @user19416: Why are you calling `AdjacencyMatrix` on something that is already a matrix? You need to do `AdjacencyGraph[s]` to get the adjacency graph.

Comment: Thanks @paw. You are awesome. Now it works. 
It works for the file that I gave you but does NOT work for a slightly different file format here. In this case the edges have weights. http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/MM/Pothen/mesh3e1.tar.gz

Comment: @paw Can you please explain what you did int he second case? Are you ignoring the edge weights in the second case? I do not want to ignore the edge weights. I expect the heavier edges to be shorter in the embedding.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what you want if you dont post it? You are very difficult to work with and I won't continue to answer you question unless I see a little bit of effort from your side. You seem like you have never taken a single look into the documentation.

Comment: @paw I apologize. I read the documentation here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GraphDrawingIntroduction.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/tutorial/GraphUtilities.html. I am new to mathematica. Is this the documentation you are talking about? Or is there a more detailed documentation available.

Comment: Read the `GraphLayout` documentation and you'll find your answer. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html

Comment: @paw Thanks a lot. I found the answer to edgeweights there. I would do s = Import["./mesh3e1.mtx"];
m = SparseArray[Most[# -> 1 & /@ ArrayRules[s][[All, 1]]]];
graph = SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[m]]
t = GraphPlot[graph, Method -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", EdgeWeighted -> True}]
Thanks.

Comment: All your edge weights are 1. But at least you found the right method to do it.

Comment: @paw Thanks for your help. You are awesome. Can you please also tell how to extract vertex coordinates. At the end of your script, I tried doing AbsoluteOptions[%, VertexCoordinates], but the coordinates do not seem to be right. (Though it is also mentioned in the documentation that VertexCoordinates dominates GraphLaylout)

Comment: `GraphEmbedding[graph]` as written before.

Comment: m = Import["mesh3e1.mtx"];
m2 = SparseArray[Most[# -> 1 & /@ ArrayRules[m][[All, 1]]]];
graph = SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[m2]];
weights = m[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ EdgeList[graph];
g = GraphPlot[m, 
  Method -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}]

Comment: You're impossible.

Comment: @paw I meant that the problem is solved. I just posted the solution. g = GraphPlot[m, 
  Method -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}]. Thanks.